# Running application within Docker containers

Tags: docker

If someone may know, does it need to be separate Dockerfile for a database and service itself in case if you want to run an application within Docker containers?

It's not quite clear where to specify the external database and server name, is it in the .env file?
https://github.com/gurock/testrail-docker/blob/master/README.md
http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-admin/installation-docker/migrating-upgrading-testrail

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should run both application and Database in a separate container.

> It's not quite clear where to specify the external database and server
>   name, is it in the .env file?

You have two option to speicy Environment variable

- .env file
- Envrionment Variables

place the .env file in the root of your docker-compose and specify this in your docker-compose file.

```
services:
  api:
    image: 'node:6-alpine'
    env_file:
     - .env
```

Using Environment

```
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER:     "${DB_USER:-testrail}"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${DB_PWD:-testrail}"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "${DB_NAME:-testrail}"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_ROOT_PWD:-my-secret-password}"
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'false'
```

> does it need to be separate Dockerfile for a database and service

Better to use offical database image, and for service, you can customize the image, but you provided link is the better choice for you to start with [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/gurock/testrail-docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml).

Also, the [documentation of docker-compose](https://github.com/gurock/testrail-docker/blob/master/docker-compose_documented.yml)  is already given in the link.

Comment: Thanks, but if you want to use docker and not docker-compose, is it significantly different setup?

Comment: No, docker compose Is just make thing easy for you

Comment: I understand that it makes it easier although if I want to use only docker, what is the approach in that case?

Comment: You can use the same approach, you just need to just dockor run and docker build command

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you can have an application and the database running in the same container, but this will have kinds of unintended consequences for example if the database falls over the application might still be running, but docker won't notice that the database fell over if it is not aware of it.

Something to wrap your mind around when running the database in a container is data persistence, which means that data would survive even when the container is killed or deleted and that once you create the container again the container would still be able to access the databases and other data.
Here is a good article explaining volumes in docker in the context of running mysql in its own container with a volume to hold the data:
https://severalnines.com/database-blog/mysql-docker-containers-understanding-basics

In context of the repo that you linked it seems there is a separate Dockerfile for the database and that you have the option to choose to use either Mariadb or MySQL, see here: 
https://github.com/gurock/testrail-docker/tree/master/Dockerfiles/testrail_mariadb

and here:

https://github.com/gurock/testrail-docker/tree/master/Dockerfiles/testrail_mysql